# Why I require more force to slide covered notebooks over each other with water between them although water work as lubricant?

Tags: forces, friction, material-science, surface-tension, adhesion

We have learnt when floor is wet we get slip as it reduce friction and work as an lubricant.

But yesterday I take 2 notebooks which are covered by transparent sheet , than I pour little  water on one notebook cover page and keep other notebook's on that first notebook on whose cover some little  water is poured.

Than I start rubbing them , but I notice I have to apply so much force to slide one notebook over other compared to without water.

Here , it is looking water is resisting, but how can this possible if water reduce friction? Notebook should slide more easily ?

[image]

Here water is between  notebooks (covered/laminated) and arrow depicting that 1st book I tried to slide on right while 2nd on left. But it require so much force than without water, how? If water is lubricant?

Comment: By the tags you have chosen it seems that you are on right track.

Answer (score 1):

This is because water has *viscosity* which becomes apparent when the water layer is very thin, and also because it is actually "sticky" in the sense that it likes to adhere to things lake paper and some plastics. So as you slide the notebooks past one another, you are *shearing* the water trapped between them- which requires work.